# Trouble finding the double derivative.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\left.\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \right|_{x=4} \cdots    y = 4x^{-3}+1x^2$$

So from what I understand this means take the double derivative. So $f'y = -12x^2+2x$ then > $f''y$ = $-24x +2$ Then I plug in $x = 4$ and I get $-94$... But the answer is still wrong. Am i doing this right?

Comment: Your mistake is that you should have $y'$ and $y''$ first of all (no $f$s); secondly, the derivative of $x^{-3}$ is $-3x^{-3-1} = -3x^{-4}$.

Comment: $f'y$ or $f'(y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should proceed as follows:

$$y=4x^{-3}+x^2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=4\cdot (-3)x^{-3-1}+2x^{2-1}=-12x^{-4}+2x$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-12\cdot (-4)x^{-4-1}+2\cdot (1)x^{1-1}=48x^{-5}+2$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}|_{x=4}=48\cdot 4^{-5}+2=3\cdot 4^{-3}+2$$

Comment: Ok, I think my problem was the algebra. I was initially moving $x^-3$ to the denominator. Thanks